# Parse server creates the same objectid in mongodb

Tags: database, mongodb, express, parse-platform, parse-server

For example, in my local parse server every time I save the object it creates the new unique object id for that particular object. But when I deploy it in live server(ec2 or some other sites) it updates the data in the same object id. (If first time I save an object. it shows me the objectid like 67XBVFA but when i create another object it updates the value in the same object id 67XBVFA.). By the way I am using mongodb for the database. Here is the simple basic which save the same object id eventhough I change the values of the field.

```
sampleobject.set("name", "xxxx");
sampleobject.set("email", "yyy@y.com");
sampleobject.save(null).then(objectstatus => {
   res.success(200, objectstatus
)}
```

Why it correctly generate a unique object id in my localhost. But updates in the same object id in live instances?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const sampleobjects = Parse.Object.extend("sampleClass");
const sampleobject = new sampleobjects();
```

The problem is I declared this in outside of the cloud function. Like this.

```
const sampleobjects = Parse.Object.extend("sampleClass");
const sampleobject = new sampleobjects();

Parse.Cloud.define('sampleFunction', (res) => {
    sampleobject.set("name", "xxxx");
    sampleobject.set("email", "yyy@y.com");
    sampleobject.save(null).then(objectstatus => {
        res.success(200, objectstatus
    )}
});
```

So every time it checks it initiates the same object id.

So when I declared it inside like this.

```
Parse.Cloud.define('sampleFunction', (res) => {
    const sampleobjects = Parse.Object.extend("sampleClass");
    const sampleobject = new sampleobjects();
    sampleobject.set("name", "xxxx");
    sampleobject.set("email", "yyy@y.com");
    sampleobject.save(null).then(objectstatus => {
        res.success(200, objectstatus
    )};
});
```